# p:fileUpload oncomplete being executed multiple times

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I want to allow my users to be able to upload between one and four images.

These images will then be attached to a single email which will be constructed and sent when the files have finished uploading.

The email cannot be sent until all the files have been attached to it.

I am using the fileUpload component in multiple mode to get the files from the user and I had hoped that I could use the oncomplete attribute in the fileUpload component to do this but it seems that this is invoked for every file which has been chosen and not when the entire list had been uploaded.

Is there a way to do a callback just once when all the files have finished uploading instead please? I can't seem to find one.

**Markup:**

```
            <p:fileUpload id = "fileChooser"
                          label="Choose File"
                          uploadLabel="Upload File(s)"
                          cancelLabel="Start Again" 
                          skinSimple="true"
                          fileUploadListener = "#{MyController.handleFileUpload}"
                          mode = "advanced"                           
                          dragDropSupport = "false"
                          multiple = "true"
                          update = "@this"
                          sizeLimit = "4000000"                           
                          fileLimit = "4" 
                          allowTypes = "/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                          oncomplete="#{MyController.uploadCompleted()}" />
```

**Bean:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
    }   

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {     
        uploadedFiles.add(event.getFile());
    }    

    public List<UploadedFile> getUploadedFiles() {
        return uploadedFiles;
    }   
    public void setUploadedFiles(List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles) {
        this.uploadedFiles = uploadedFiles;
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -261758226698276865L;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);

    @Inject
    private MyBean myBean; 

    // This is hit every single time a file finishes uploading which is unwanted behaviour.
    public void uploadCompleted() {
        LOG.info("Uploading finished, Number of files:" + myBean.getUploadedFiles().size());
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        LOG.info("New file upload event passed to event handler");
        LOG.info("File Name :" + event.getFile().getFileName() + " File Size:" + event.getFile().getSize());
        myBean.upload(event);       
    }

    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        return uploadNonUKLicenceBean;
    }
    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, as files are chosen they are added into a list contained in the fileUpload files property, as the files are uploaded then they are removed from this so using p:remoteCommand I've just checked the length of this so that I can call the method I want in my controller when it's empty.

(There was a bug in my original question with the oncomplete attribute which crept in there when I was sanitising the code to post here, I've corrected it in the answer as per the comments).

If there's a better way of doing it I'd love to know.

```
<p:fileUpload id = "fileChooser"
              label="Choose File"
              uploadLabel="Upload File(s)"
              cancelLabel="Start Again" 
              fileUploadListener = "#{nonUKLicenceCheckController.handleFileUpload}"
              mode = "advanced"                           
              dragDropSupport = "false"
              multiple = "true"
              update = "@this"
              sizeLimit = "4000000"                           
              fileLimit = "4" 
              allowTypes = "/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
              widgetVar="uploadWidget"
              oncomplete="isFileListEmpty(PF('uploadWidget'), uploadsFinished);"
              />            
<p:remoteCommand name="uploadsFinished" actionListener="#{nonUKLicenceCheckController.uploadCompleted()}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isFileListEmpty(fileupload, finished) {
    if (fileupload.files.length === 0) {
            if (finished) {
                finished();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And you changed the value of the oncomplete to calling javascript instead of a bean (which won't work)

Comment: @Kukeltje it calls the remoteCommand called "uploadsFinished" if the javascript to check if the files list is empty returns true. It seems to be working for me.

Comment: In your question you have `oncomplete="#{MyController.uploadCompleted()}"` That won't work!

Comment: Oh, I see - so I have. I misunderstood what you meant, my apologies.